# Creating java RESTful application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jersey

1. I want to create new RESTful application. I am bit confused about framework I can do it with spring+jersey , but can I do same application using jersey alone?
2. What is major difference between SpringREST and jersey?
   Which is more convenient? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that Jersey is standards-based, and Spring MVC is not, if that matters to you. Both are very good.

The main advantage I found in Jersey (I used 1.x) was that it could automatically use Jackson JSON Views automatically, and Spring MVC could not. Also, error handling in Spring MVC is kind of irritating, as error pages default to standard HTML.

There is another project you have not listed, and that is Spring Data + Spring HATEOAS, which is newer, but seems pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

I've used both frameworks a bit. Spring is a large framework/API that covers many areas, one of which is rest services. Jersey on the other hand just covers rest. It's the reference implementation for the JAX-RS API (JSR 311 & JSR 339).

This is basically the "standard" way to do rest in Java. There are also other implementations like RestEasy. In theory your code will only need to reference the common JAX-RS interfaces meaning you ought to be able to swap to a different implementation later if required. This obviously only works if you don't become reliant on bespoke functionality that isn't part of the JAX-RS standard.

If you were to use Jersey, you might still decide you want spring. It can be useful just for its dependency injection alone. In this case you might have a JAX-RS class handling rest requests which then calls a spring service which has been injected. This is actually how I'm writing rest API's.

Whether you should use spring to write the rest services or JAX-RS is subjective and really up to you. Personally I went with the standard JAX-RS API because I found it was more focused on rest. The spring rest approach is basically an extension of spring-mvc which was originally intended for JSP's. I found things like error handling were easier using JAX-RS than spring-mvc. That said someone else may beg to differ. The other benefit is by following the standard in theory you have more flexibility in future if you want to switch to a different provider.